# Constrain Sum(Column) to 1 by some group ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a table that I'm trying to make sure that an aggregate sum of the inserts adds up to 1 (it's a mixture).
[image: dbo.Test]

I want to constrain it so the whole FKID =2 fails because it adds up to 1.1.

Currently my constraint is

```
FUNCTION[dbo].[CheckSumTarget](@ID bigint)
RETURNS bit
AS BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Res BIT
    SELECT @Res = Count(1)
    FROM dbo.Test AS t
    WHERE t.FKID = @ID 
    GROUP BY t.FKID
    HAVING Sum([t.Value])<>1    
    RETURN @Res
END
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Target_Sum] CHECK  (([dbo].[CheckSumTarget]([FKID])<>(1)))
```

but it's failing on the first insert because it doesn't add up to 1 yet.  I was hoping if I add them all simultaneously, that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

This approach seems fraught with problems.

I would suggest another approach, starting with two tables:

- `aggregates`, so "fkid" should really be `aggregate_id`
- `components`

Then, in `aggregates` accumulate the `sum()` of the component values using a trigger.  Maintain *another* flag that is computed:

```
 alter table aggregates add is_valid as ( sum_value = 1.0 )
```

Then, create views on the two tables to only show records where `is_valid = 1`.  For instance:

```
create view v_aggregates as
    select c.*
    from aggregates a join
         components c
         on a.aggregate_id = c.aggregate_id
    where a.is_value = 1;
```

Comment: But if a user puts in some values that are not valid, wouldn't it just look like they just lost their values?

Comment: @Faller . . . Are you trying to prevent users from changing values that add up to 1?

Comment: Users enter components of a mixture in percentages.  I'm making sure those components add up to 1 (100%).

Comment: @Faller, in database the best approach you can get is a mix or this computed column and the constraint to prevent sums greater than 1, the rest needs to be done in business layer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of solution

Here is table DDL

```
create table dbo.test(
    id      int,
    fkid    bigint,
    value   decimal(4,2)
);
```

The function definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION[dbo].[CheckSumTarget](@ID bigint)
RETURNS bit
AS BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Res decimal(4,2)
    SELECT @Res = case when sum(value) > 1 then 1 else 0 end 
    FROM dbo.Test AS t
    WHERE t.FKID = @ID  
    RETURN @Res
END
```

And the constraint defintion

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Target_Sum] CHECK ([dbo].[CheckSumTarget]([FKID]) <> 1)
```

In your example

```
insert into dbo.test values (1, 2, 0.5);
insert into dbo.test values (1, 2, 0.4);
-- The following insert will fail, like you expect
insert into dbo.test values (1, 2, 0.2);
```

**Note:** This solution will be broken by UPDATE statement (as pointed out by 'Daniel Brughera') however that is a known behaviour. A better and common approach is use of trigger. You may want to explore that.

Comment: Yes the update will break this. The better solution is use of a trigger

Comment: The check can work if you add the value column to the constraint, it’s failing because the fkid wasn’t updated, so, the constraint is not checked again, my approach works for that, but I agree that is not the best solution

Comment: But this only works for greater than.  I need it to add to 1 exactly.

Comment: Do you mean my refined solution? it works well in my testing. Allows inserts exactly until sum(value)  <= 1.0, fails after that...

Comment: @Faller, the exact 1 is not possible, not with constraints, the constraints are validated per row and column, so it will take the same behavior as check (value = 1) all the time

Answer (score 1):

Your actual approach will work this way.....

1. You insert the firts component, the value must be 1
2. You try to insert a second component, it will be rejected because your sum is already 1
3. You update the existing component to .85
4. You insert the next component, the value must be .15
5. You back to step 2. with the third component

Since your constraint only takes care of the FKID column, it will be possible, and you may think that is working....

But.... if you left the process in step 3. your sum is not equal to 1 and is impossible for the constraint to foresee if you will insert the next value or not, even worst, you can update any value to be greater than 1 and it will be accepted.

If you add the value column to your constraint, it will prevent those updates, but you will never be able to go beyond step 1.

Personally I would't do that, but here you can get an approach

1. Use the computed column suggested by Gordon on your parent table. With computed columns you will always get the actual value, so, the parent wont be valid until the sum is equal to one
2. Use this solution to prevent the value to be greater than 1, so, at least you will be sure that any non valid parent is because a component is missing, that can be helpful for your business layer
3. As I mentioned in one comment, the rest of the logic belongs to the business and ui layers

**Note** as you can see the id and value parameters are not used in the function, but I need them to call them when I create the constraint, that way the constraint will validate updates too

```
 CREATE TABLE ttest (id int, fkid int, value float)
     go
     create FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckSumTarget](@id int, @fkid int, @value float)
     RETURNS FLOAT
     AS BEGIN 
         DECLARE @Res float
         SELECT @Res = sum(value)
         FROM dbo.ttest AS t
         WHERE t.FKID = @fkid 
         RETURN @Res
     END
     GO
     ALTER TABLE dbo.ttest  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Target_Sum] CHECK  (([dbo].[CheckSumTarget](id,[FKID],value)<=(1.0)))
```